# Integrating toggl button isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate Toggl button in few websites. 
I did what is [written here](https://github.com/toggl/toggl-button/wiki/Adding-new-integrations).
My code in forbes.js looks like:

```
/*jslint indent: 2 */
/*global $: false, document: false, togglbutton: false*/
'use strict';

togglbutton.render('#task:not(.toggl)', {observe: true}, function (elem) {
var link,
description = $('.title', elem).textContent,
project = $('.project', elem).textContent;

link = togglbutton.createTimerLink({
className: 'forbes',
description: description,
projectName: project
});

$('container-fluid').appendChild(link);
});
```

But if i try to test it nothing happens. I think I made a mistake in:

```
$('container-fluid').appendChild(link);
```

But I don't know how to correct it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you forgot to define the class or the id of your "container-fluid"

Comment: @smdsgn Its already predefined in page which I want to edit, it is chrome extension which should show Toggl timer in that element.

Comment: You are using a DOM method with a jQuery object. Try with the append jQuery method instead. $('container-fluid').append(link);

Comment: Also, I think you have not understood correctly my first comment. I was talking about this line $('container-fluid').appendChild(link); Your jQuery object does not have any class or id selector ("." or "#").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
**For clarification about selectors and javascript method used in Toggl-button.** 
Because your question is tagged with javascript and jquery, I thought you try to use a DOM method "appendChild" on a jQuery object. But it's not. After receiving a kind explanation from Indrek from toggl-button, $ is defined in common.js and uses document.querySelector under the hood. 
[see here](https://github.com/toggl/toggl-button/blob/master/src/scripts/common.js#L5).
**So your only error was in your CSS selector.**

So your problem was in this line `$('container-fluid').appendChild(link);`
She should be like this `$('.container-fluid').appendChild(link);`
**Sorry for my mistake.**

**END OF UPDATE**

To resume my comments I think you have two errors :
First you try to use a DOM method  "appendChild" on a jQuery object.
 You have to use the "append" jQuery method instead if you want to use a jQuery object.
Also, your jQuery object doesn't have a class or id selector "." for class and "#" for id.
So if your element has the id "container-fluid", you need to use it like this :

```
$('#container-fluid').append(link);
```

But if your element has the class "container-fluid", you need to use it like this :

```
$('.container-fluid').append(link);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt understand javascript/jQuery a lot. I just trying to implement function using tutorial. I thought in the $('THERE').append(link); should be a class from html tag. Did I thought wrong or not? Thank you.

Comment: You're close, Denis. You put the CSS selector there. The answer provided by @smdsgn should solve your problem.

Comment: Fixed the instructions on the github page to reflect that you should use `$.append()` rather than `$.appendChild()`. Can't believe that was even there...

Comment: You right @Denis, you just have to write it like this $('.yourClass').append(link); Don't forget the "." before your class name.

Comment: Thank you, so, I have now $('.share-buttons').append(link); but it is still not working. Chrome developer console give me this error: Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: $(...).append is not a function
    at chrome-extension://mdcfbhcfaidmonaajkpajecfjlndbdjm/scripts/content/pc-help.js:17:23
    at Object.togglbutton.renderTo (chrome-extension://mdcfbhcfaidmonaajkpajecfjlndbdjm/scripts/common.js:126:7)
    at chrome-extension://mdcfbhcfaidmonaajkpajecfjlndbdjm/scripts/common.js:115:21

Comment: And if you try with the appendChild method, like in the toggl button documentation like this $('.share-buttons').appendChild(link); do you have an error ?

Comment: You're welcome @Denis I have update my answer to explain why you need to use the appendChild DOM method.